# Show required pop-up (bubble) of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used `e.preventDefault();` to disable scrolling page to invalid `input`. I'm tried for that `scrollintoview(false)`, with by default scroll site to top, but it doesn't do anything.

Now, for scrolling page to invalid `input`, I'm using my own function that center element on screen.

Unfortunately, with this method I also disabled a warning bubble and `focus` on invalid element. Triggering focus it's not hard - `input.focus();`. But what should I do, to show input error bubbly by JS? For some reason, I can't use `form.reportValidity()` function. I need something like `input.triggerError();`

```js
// JS code, to center site on element:

// event.preventDefault();
// var elOffset = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
// var elHeight = element.height();
// var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
// var offset;

// if (elHeight < windowHeight) {
//   offset = elOffset - ((windowHeight / 2) - (elHeight / 2));
// }
// else {
//   offset = elOffset;
// }
// window.scrollTo(0, offset);
// element.focus();


// I CAN'T DO THIS:
// FORM.reportValidity();


// I'm searching for sth like this:
// element.reportValidity();
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
.fixed-menu h1,
.fixed-menu p {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
}
.fixed-menu {
    background-color: #222;
    border-color: #080808;
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-menu">
  <h1>This is fixed menu</h1>
  <p>I'm using e.preventDefault(); to disable that activity</p>
</div>

<form>
<br>
<label>this is input:
<input type="text" required>
</label>

<p style="margin-bottom: 100px"><b>Tip:</b><br>
1. leave this input, and srcoll to submit button.<br>
2. click on it.<br>
3. see - scroll is not good enought</p>


<button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So you're main objective is to [show that input box] that contains the 'invalid data' by the time you've [click the 'Submit form']?

Comment: @eeya Yeah, but I think that this is done. If You look on JS code above, You will see that I calculated "center" position, script can scroll to them and focus input. The problem is pop-up/bubble/tooltip from input - it doesn't show :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is some hints that helps explaining my solution :

- I see what you did when you have styled the body element `margin-top: 70px;`
  that worked in the snippet but not in the browser, so I've opted to a slightly different solution with the same spirit, that's the explanation of the css
  Now to the nitty-gritty :
- You use the [`invalid`event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid) on the input element and you use [`scrollBy` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy) to scroll the element down by `70px` of the fixed menu + any margin or border hence `-80`
- You may ask why using `setTimout` instead of directly calling `scrollBy` inside the handler, the answer is that will not work because it will be in *conflict* with other actions that JavaScript consider more important which are : the not good enough scrolling and the displaying the label.
  The solution to that is in adding `scrollBy` to the queue of actions by calling it asynchronously by `setTimout`

```js
document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("invalid",function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
  scrollBy(0,-80)
 },0)
})
```

```css
.body {

  position:relative;
}
.fixed-menu h1,
.fixed-menu p {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
}
.fixed-menu {
    background-color: #222;
    border-color: #080808;
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    height: 70px;
}
Form{
 position:absolute;
 top:70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-menu">
 <h1>This is fixed menu</h1>
 <p>I'm using e.preventDefault(); to disable that activity</p>
</div>

<form>
 <br>
 <label>this is input:
  <input id="inp" type="text" required>
 </label>

 <p style="margin-bottom: 100px">
  <b>Tip:</b><br>
  1. leave this input, and srcoll to submit button.<br>
  2. click on it.<br>
  3. see - scroll is now good enought
 </p>

 <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```